# Style is distorting in DataTables

Tags: asp.net, datatables, mvc.jquery.datatables

Below is my scripts config code

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bs-init.js",
                  "~/Scripts/chart.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/theme.js",
                  "~/Scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js",
                  "~/Scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

This is my CSS config code

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/fontawesome-all.min.css",
                  "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                  "~/Content/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css",
                  "~/Content/Bold-BS4-Footer-Simple.css",
                  "~/Content/x-dropdown.css",
                  "~/Content/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

This is how I am using Jquery

@section scripts{

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#productTable").DataTable();
    }

        );

</script>
```

}

I am using DataTable pluging with bootstrap in ASP.NET Web Application. But the style is distorting and pagination buttons appearing on side. Can't figure out how to fix it. If you can help, I am attaching the ss below
[image]

Comment: I think you placed the script tags in the wrong order.
The right order is 
include "datatable jquery"
include "datatable bootstrap"
Do forgive me if I'm wrong cause I'm just taking a wild guess here considering that all I see is just a screenshot.

Comment: @RyanLim Thank you bro! The problem was of order of script files. The correct order is just opposite of your suggested order

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the scripts order. To fix, datatables.bootstrap.js file must before the file jquery.datatables.js

Like this

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bs-init.js",
                  "~/Scripts/chart.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/theme.js",
                  "~/Scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```